# Is There a Pandoc Latex Template For Novel or Short Story Manuscript Submissions?

Tags: style, publishing

I use *Markdown* to write my stories, and have started using Pandoc to convert to PDFs and HTML. The PDFs could use improvement, however, and I would like to make them look like Manuscript submissions.

Comment: I'm not sure that pdf is the right output format if you want the document to approximate typical manuscript submission formatting. Have you tried seeing what the .rtf or .docx outputs look like?

Comment: Surely the proper format depends on where you're submitting to....

Comment: Have you seen: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/User-contributed-templates

Comment: There is LaTeX `novel` class, but it's (on purpose) quite incompatible with standard LaTeX markup commands. Further, it's not the _logic_ layout (that was, quite successfully, even if not in a complete form, attempted in LaTeX), but rather a _formatting_ tool, similar to ConTeXt or original TeX.

Answer (score 3):

[bookdown](https://bookdown.org/home/) would be a simple, easy way to write books in Markdown.

For a start, one can follow the tutorial itself to make a authentic looking manuscript.

Here are the directions to develop templates: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/templates.html